# Restrict drive access on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have a 2 TB Data drive. How can I deny access to it for specific users in my domain after 4 PM?

Is there any group policy that can do this?

Best Regards

Comment: You could configure a script on the server that leverages the `NET SHARE` command to [modify permissions to the share](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/dont-forget-about-net-share) via which the users access the drive.  Be warned you would have to delete/re-create the share to accomplish this.